# How to spilt string in a sql column and store it in other column based on string length

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have declared a temporary table inside a stored procedure where i have four column for address
e.g AddressLine1, AddressLine2,AddressLine3,AddressLine4 each of which have length Varchar(50)

i want to insert data inside the temp table from existing table so that existing table stored the address inside AddressLine1
so i want to insert Address in AddressLine1 from existing table to temporary table but if Address exceeds length of 50 with spaces then i want to insert remaining address to AddressLine2 and so on

so in all i want to divide address based on length of the column which is 50 and then store it amongst
addressLine1,addressLine2,addressLine3,addressLine4 in temporary table

```
select DATALENGTH(ADDRESSLINE1)
from PASSENGER
where DATALENGTH(ADDRESSLINE1) > 50
```

Comment: if you just want to chop the string at fixed position then a simple `substring()` will do the job

Comment: @Squirrel if i use substring it will split string on fix charecter like 50 but if on that place there is a continuation of word from address then that word would get split to next column so i want a solution that fix this

Comment: Please read [this](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question. Sample data and expected results would help us help you. What are valid characters to split on? Space? Comma? Dash?

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by some recursive cte and substring... following a quick example which can for sure be optimized / shortened but which should make clear the point:

```
DECLARE @x NVARCHAR(200) = N'This is some test and this still is the test and yet here the test continues and so on until the test is finished';

WITH cte1 AS(
-- evaluate all positions of spaces
SELECT @x as txt, CHARINDEX(' ', @x) as idx
UNION ALL
SELECT txt, CHARINDEX(' ', txt, idx+1) as idx
  FROM cte1
  WHERE CHARINDEX(' ', txt, idx+1) >0
),
cte2 AS(
-- evaluate groups basing of the length of 50 as desired output length
SELECT *, idx/50 - CASE WHEN idx%50 = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS dividx
  FROM cte1
),
cte3 AS(
-- evaluate max space position per group
SELECT txt, dividx, max(idx) maxIdx
  FROM cte2
  GROUP BY txt, dividx
),
cte4 AS(
-- evaluate required start and end position for substring operation
SELECT txt, dividx
      ,ISNULL(LAG(maxIdx) OVER (PARTITION BY txt ORDER BY dividx)+1, 1) AS minIdx
      ,CASE WHEN LEAD(maxIdx) OVER (PARTITION BY txt ORDER BY dividx) IS NULL THEN len(txt) ELSE maxIdx END AS maxIdx
  FROM cte3
)
-- perform substring
SELECT SUBSTRING(txt, minIdx, maxIdx-minIdx+1) AS txt
  FROM cte4
  OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```